# Wait for and trap only first level child processes

Tags: ruby, concurrency, process, ruby-2.2

Ruby provides tools like `Process.wait` and `Signal.trap` to synchronize the forked processes. But how can you make sure that you will register only for first level child processes? E.g. if your main process starts process *A* and that one stars another subprocess *B*. If I use `wait`/`trap` in my main process, how can I specify interest in direct sub-processes like *A* and not sub-subprocesse like *B*?

For example:

```
Signal.trap("CLD")  { counter += 1 }    
Process.wait if counter <= 0
counter -= 1
fork { … }
```

I use this technique to limit the number of spawned child processes. But this breaks if child processes spawn more subprocesses.

Comment: Could you show us some code? That would make it easier to pick up what you're trying trying to do, and having trouble with..

Comment: @cozyconemotel added